# How generate a JWT token for Metabase using Apex

Tags: apex, jwt

I have to embed a Metabase Iframe into Salesforce via an lwc.

The metabase itself gives me the code below in Node.js as an example.

```js
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var METABASE_SITE_URL = "METABASE_SITE_URL";
var METABASE_SECRET_KEY = "15480e3f631b3ff5a1dcfa9d2efdbfc94395e66ecdcc238f2";
var payload = {
  resource: { question: 1209 },
  params: {},
  exp: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) + (10 * 60) // 10 minute expiration
};
var token = jwt.sign(payload, METABASE_SECRET_KEY);
var iframeUrl = METABASE_SITE_URL + "/embed/question/" + token + "#bordered=false&titled=false";
```

Now I am trying to adapt this code to Apex and it has been a really painful journey.

I've tried using `JWT` class, `JWS` and `Crypto`, but so far without success.

There is extensive documentation of people using JWS to connect to Salesforce, but so far I haven't found an example implementation where Token is generated in Salesforce without hitting third party endpoints.

UPDATE

The point is how can I generate a JWT token in apex using only the header, the payload and the key?

UPDATE 2

I finally made it!

```
String header = '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}';
String payload = '{"resource":{"question":1209},"params":{},"exp":1571678680,"iat":1569518680}';
String key = '19bce9bf8c9dc1255480e3f631b3ff5a1dcfa9d2efdbfc94395e66ecdcc238f2';

String header64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header));

header64 = header64.replaceAll('=','');
header64 = header64.replaceAll('-','');
header64 = header64.replaceAll('/','');

String payload64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(payload));

payload64 = payload64.replaceAll('=','');
payload64 = payload64.replaceAll('-','');
payload64 = payload64.replaceAll('/','');

Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(header64 + '.' + payload64), Blob.valueOf(key));

String signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);

String token = header64 + '.' + payload64 + '.' + signature;
token = token.replaceAll('=','');
token = token.replaceAll('-','');
token = token.replaceAll('/','');
```

Comment: Unless you include where you are stuck code wise, this question is most likely going to be closed

Comment: May be this would help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235487/jwt-cyrpto-sign-and-encodingutil-base64encode

Answer (score 2):

A [Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) can issue JWTs out of the box. Unfortunately your Metabase service is expecting a JWT in a URL and Named Credential does not support this as doing so is not a best practice. Here's how you can do it in Apex:

```
Map<String,Map<String,Object>> claims = new Map<String,Map<String,Object>>();
Map<String,Object> resource = new Map<String,Object>();
resource.put('question',1209);
claims.put('resource',resource);

Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
jwt.setAdditionalClaims(claims);
Auth.JWS signedToken = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'MyKeyPairName');
String serializedToken = signedToken.getCompactSerialization();
System.debug(serializedToken);
```

Adding the `exp`iration claim is left as an exercise for the reader.

You have to upload or generate a keypair (private/public key) via [Certificates and Key Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=security_keys_about.htm&type=5) in the admin console. *MyKeyPairName* is the value of `UniqueName` field on the Certificates detail screen. SF will use the private key from the keypair to sign the JWT.

Comment: Thank you @identigral.

I'm receiving a very larger and complex token than Metabase can use.

But I believe that I'm in the right path now.

Thank you.